# Remote desktop software for Linux PCs?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, remote-access

I need to connect to Linux computers from remote. I am using LogMeIn for windows PCs. But it doesn't have client for Linux boxes.

I have tried Team Viewer, but seems very heavy.

Is there any other solution for this??

Comment: Most people just use SSH, and X11 forwarding when needed for admin stuff.

Answer (score 4):

One of the VNC client variants would be a good choice. There are several forks, I use TightVNC but YMMV.

Comment: Any Other hosted solutions like LogMeIn?

Answer (score 1):

NoMachine (NX Free Edition in 3.5.0) for Linux will let you access Linux boxes. On your local desktop you'll need to install their client: NoMachine Player (NX Client 3.5.0). They also just released NoMachine for remote access to Windows PCs and Macs.

Answer (score 0):

Either try using vnc (x11vnc or something) if you need the whole desktop, or ssh with X forwarding (ssh -X) to forward just one window/app.